# Plinqo 4 vs EF 4

Tags: entity-framework, plinqo

Does anyone has experience with plinqo 4? 
what are the benefits vs EF 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good answer to this is on the PLINQO site itself

http://www.plinqo.com/why-plinqo.ashx

I looked at EF, NHibernate and Subsonic and finally rested with PLINQO as it seems to have the best bits of all the ORMS without too much of the bloat. Plus sitting on top of LINQ2SQL its pretty fast.

You can only really judge this by trying it yourself but I would save yourself some time and try PLINQO before EF.

Comment: What about EF 4? 
There is some benefits?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we use PLINQ, it's Extremley good and provides out of the box support for ADO.NET Data Services and WCF Data Contracts.

Answer (score 1):

PLINQO has better serialization across the wire options as well.